# Why is there extra space on right and bottom of the website?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to remove the white space at the bottom and right side of the website. On the right side it seems that it's caused by the black navbar but I don't have a clue how to fix it.

```css
/* Navbar */

.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-fixed-top.scrolled {
  background: black;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.non-underline {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff!important;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-nav>li>a:active,
.navbar-nav>li>a.active {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff!important;
}

#logo-img {
  width: 70%;
}


/* End Navbar */


/* Jumbotron */

#first {
  padding: 0;
}

.jumbotron-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

h2>a {
  color: #565656;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#h1first {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
}


/* End Jumbotron */


/* About */

#abouth2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#about-section {
  padding-top: 8%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.fadeInBlock {
  opacity: 0;
}

#p-about {
  font-size: 180%;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

#img-about {
  padding: 0;
}


/*End About*/


/*Portfolio*/

#portfolio-section {
  background-color: ;
  background: #B5927E;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #B5927E, #6C5461);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #B5927E, #6C5461);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #B5927E, #6C5461);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #B5927E, #6C5461);
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.headline {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  color: #484A4A;
}

.headline.fadeInBlock>a {
  color: #484A4A;
}

.headline.fadeInBlock>a:hover {
  color: #484A4A;
}

#portfolio-id {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}


/*End Portfolio*/


/*Contact*/

#contact-section {
  background-color: #4D3C4F;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.social-icons {
  color: #b7b7b7;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.fa-facebook-official {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
}

.fa-twitter {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
}

.fa-free-code-camp {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
}

.fa-envelope {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
}

#facebook:hover {
  color: #3b5998;
}

#twitter:hover {
  color: #00aced;
}

#fcc:hover {
  color: #006401;
}

#email:hover {
  color: #92b8f4;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/*End Contact*/


/*Footer*/

footer {
  background-color: #382F4A;
}

#copy {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}


/*End Footer*/
```

```html
<!--Navbar-->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/27wy82r.png" id="logo-img"></a>
      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Navbar-->
<!--Jumbotron-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="jumbotron" id="first" href="#home">
      <img class="jumbotron-image" src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2014/07/featured36.jpg">
      <h1 class="text-center fadeInPage" id="h1first">
        Welcome to Cosmos<br> web design
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Jumbotron-->
<!--About-->
<div class="container" id="about-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class="text-center" id="abouth2"><a name="about">About</a></h2>
      <p class="fadeInBlock" id="p-about">Cosmos Web Design was created by George Kech. I provide web solutions that require HTML, CSS, JavaScript and JQuery. I focus on serving the needs of each customer individually with complete satisfaction as my goal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="https://www.topechelon.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/devices-web-design.png" alt="web design" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End About-->
<!--Portfolio-->
<div class="container-inner" id="portfolio-section">
  <h2 class="text-center headline fadeInBlock" id="portfolio-id"><a name="portfolio">Portfolio</a> is coming soon...</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-fj6pace2cv0/U9Jt75Kq8PI/AAAAAAAARtE/ttg-4YuCOfQ/s250/exe_empty_thumbnail.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-fj6pace2cv0/U9Jt75Kq8PI/AAAAAAAARtE/ttg-4YuCOfQ/s250/exe_empty_thumbnail.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-fj6pace2cv0/U9Jt75Kq8PI/AAAAAAAARtE/ttg-4YuCOfQ/s250/exe_empty_thumbnail.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Portfolio-->
<!--Contact-->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="contact-section">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="text-center">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/georgefilmographia"><i class="social-icons fa fa-facebook-official" id="facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/kech_george"><i class="social-icons fa fa-twitter" id="twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/georgemitnick"><i class="social-icons fa fa-free-code-camp" id="fcc"></i></a>
        <a href="georgebigmoviefreak@gmail.com"><i class="social-icons fa fa-envelope" id="email"></i></a>
        <h3 id="contactMe">
          <a name="contact"></a>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Contact-->
<!--Footer-->
<footer>
  <p class="text-center" id="copy">George Kech &copy; 2017</p>
</footer>
```

And here's the link to the codepen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/georgekech/pen/ZLNMGE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by your Bootstrap:
Every `.row` has a negative margin left and right, while every `.col-*` has a padding left and right by the same amount.

We have to get rid of that. But we need it back inside `.container` classes.

Look here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpOyyo

I added this CSS:

```
/* Don't add padding to all elements that have classes like "col-md-*" */
[class^="col-md-"], 
[class*=" col-md-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
/* Add back the Bootstrap padding, if inside .container */
.container [class^="col-md-"], 
.container [class*=" col-md-"] {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

/* Don't add negative margin for all rows */
.row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

/* Add back the Bootstrap margin, if inside .container */
.container .row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Update: Add this as well to address the footer issue.

```
.container-fluid {
  padding-right:0px;
  padding-left:0px;
}

footer p{
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: @Sicae Thanks for the edit. I totally overread the bottom issue. But in my opinion Serg Chernata's answer is the correct one, as is addresses the bootstrap way, while my answer is fiddling around and a little bit too nitty gritty.

Comment: I tried to add .container-fluid like Serg Chernata says but it doesn't solve the issue. It creates an extra space on the left and right.

Comment: The solution was to remove .row and .col-12. It works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's your top level nesting. You need to wrap the jumbotron into a container div as well. You can make it fluid if you need full width:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    ...
</div>
```

Generally speaking, if you look at basic [templates provided by boostrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples-framework), they place all body content into a container div.

This is due to the fact that each row has a `-15px` margin.

Comment: When I put the jumbotron in a div container-fluid it fixes the lower part extra space but it creates extra left and right space for the jumbotron.

Comment: All I'm saying is, pay attention to the nesting and look at examples provided. I don't know what your current code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

its caused by the padding-right on the div .col-md-12. Set it to 0 and its fine.
The white space at the bottom is caused by the #copy in the footer, add margin-bottom: 0 to it.

Comment: That solves only the navbar and jumbotron section extra space.

Comment: also add margin-bottom: 0 to #copy in the footer, I edit my answer